# what is the best way for this condition

Tags: batch-file

can someone please tell me how can I make a batch file the inputs 5 numbers and checks for each number if its even ir odd? i dont know what i did wrong about the module part:

```
@echo off

for /l %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
                    set /p num1=
                    set /a "mod=%num1% %% 2"
                    echo mod=%mod%
                    if mod EQU 0 (echo EVEN!)else echo ODD!
                    echo.
                  )
echo 5 numbers were inputed.
echo.
pause
```

and another question: Can I not declare the num1 variable and check if its even inside the if (having a mathematical expression inside the if and not only a simple comparison)?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do mathematical computations within an IF statement.

Here are some problems with your code:

- Normal expansion occurs when a statement is parsed, and all code within your FOR loop is parsed in one pass. So `%mod%` expands to a constant value - the value that existed before the FOR loop begain (or empty string if mod was not defined).
- Variables must be expanded if you want to use them in an IF statement.

Not a bug - but numeric variables do not need to be expanded to use them in a SET /A statement.

Here is one solution - have the loop call a subroutine that gets reparsed each iteration:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do call :test
echo 5 numbers were inputed.
echo(
pause
exit /b

:test
set /p "num1=Enter a number: "
set /a "mod=num1 %% 2"
echo mod=%mod%
if %mod% EQU 0 (echo EVEN!)else echo ODD!
echo(
```

Another option is to enable and use delayed expansion. Unquoted `!` literals must be escaped as `^^!` if delayed expansion is enabled. Not needed here, but a quoted `!` would be escaped as `"^!"`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
  set /p "num1=Enter a number: "
  set /a "mod=num1 %% 2"
  echo mod=!mod!
  if !mod! EQU 0 (echo EVEN^^!)else echo ODD^^!
  echo(
)
echo 5 numbers were inputed.
echo(
pause
exit /b
```

If you do not need to print out the mod value, you can use a math trick to avoid use of CALL or delayed expansion. You can divide by the mod value, and it will raise an error if mod is 0. You can conditionally take action using `&&` for success (odd) and `||` for failure (even).

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
  set /p "num1=Enter a number: "
  set /a "1/(num1 %% 2)" 2>nul &&echo ODD!||ECHO EVEN!
  echo(
)
echo 5 numbers were inputed.
echo(
pause
exit /b
```

Comment: You can also test the 1st bit to see if it is odd or even.

Comment: @foxidrive - Oh man, it took me a while to realize you were referring to the low order bit (one's place) of the binary representation. At first I was thinking "test the 1st bit of code" Huh? LOL

Comment: hehe  oops!  yes, bit zero is what I should have said.

Comment: why do i have to add a sub function using callin order to make the module? isnt it possible from within the main code?

Comment: @user3599541 - ??? Only the first option that uses regular expansion requires CALL. The 2nd and 3rd options work within the loop without requiring CALL.